# Ektron searches are not returning results

Tags: ektron

I am trying to query for documents matching a criteria using the Ektron CMS UI (Navigate to the Folder containing the documents and click on Action -> Search). Not getting any results for any criteria. The Documents are getting listed when I navigate the entire folder contents and that confirms they are present in the CMS though. The SearchConfigUI is executed successfully and the Indexing Service is up and running. Any thoughts on why the indexing is not getting propagated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on version 8.0, a recent Microsoft automatic update affected Microsoft Index Server, which is the search technology used for indexing and querying in version 8.0. Take a look at this thread:
http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=40811

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. This is the exact cause of the problem. Uninstalling the above security update resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Basic search under action search, it uses the search system. When you use the advanced search instead, it uses a database query. That may be a solution.

For troubleshooting index search, see 
http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v802/WebHelp/Navigating/Search/search_troubleshooting.htm